# Is there a way to look into an index that is in another index into an IF condition?

Tags: php, json

I'm tearing my hair out with one tiny little problem.

I get several JSON from an API that I created, and add them together in an array that I decode and then return the information to me in cleartext.

I'd like, in an if, to find a way to indicate that if in one of the JSON some information is right compared to the information passed as a function parameter, make a boolean variable return True.

For the moment what is returned to me is the following:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { ["idUserBrasserie"]=> int(1) ["fK_idUser"]=> int(1) ["fK_idBrasserie"]=> int(1) } [1]=> array(5) { ["idUser"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(6) "Mat" ["lastName"]=> string(4) "Anderson" ["email"]=> string(16) "brewdawg@beer.ch" ["pwd"]=> string(10) "1234567890" } [2]=> array(3) { ["idBrasserie"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(8) "BrewDawg" ["description"]=> string(22) "Craft beer and sausage" } }
Notice: Undefined index: fK_idBrasserie in /var/www/html/Controllers/MaBrasserieController.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: in /var/www/html/Controllers/MaBrasserieController.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: fK_idBrasserie in /var/www/html/Controllers/MaBrasserieController.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: in /var/www/html/Controllers/MaBrasserieController.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: fK_idBrasserie in /var/www/html/Controllers/MaBrasserieController.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: in /var/www/html/Controllers/MaBrasserieController.php on line 21
bool(false)
```

Here's the php part in the view :

```
<?php MaBrasserieController::GetUserBrasserie(1,1,1)?>
```

And here's the function in my controller :

```
public static function GetUserBrasserie($idUserBrasserie, $fk_idBrasserie, $fk_idUser){
        $myBrewery = false;
            $json_url = 'http://backend:5000/api/User_Brasserie/'.$idUserBrasserie;
                $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
            $json_url_User = 'http://backend:5000/api/User/'.$fk_idUser;
                $json_User = file_get_contents($json_url_User);
            $json_url_Brasserie = 'http://backend:5000/api/Brasserie/'.$fk_idBrasserie;
                $json_Brasserie = file_get_contents($json_url_Brasserie);
        $array[]=json_decode($json,true);
        $array[]=json_decode($json_User, true);
        $array[]=json_decode($json_Brasserie, true);
        $data = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        $result = json_decode($data, true);
        var_dump($result);
       foreach ($result as $item){
            if($item[$array["fK_idBrasserie"]]===$fK_idBrasserie && $item[$array["fK_idUser"]]===$fK_idUser) {
                $myBrewery = true;
            }
        }
        var_dump($myBrewery);
        return $myBrewery;
    }
```

The bool $myBrewery is returned False and i wish for it to return True if the condition is right.

Is anyone have an idea of how can I make this work?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. We don’t have your actual JSON data, so please provide examples of that, so that what you have shown becomes reproducible for people here.

Comment: Your code `$array[]=` will create numeric indexes (in order) of each thing that you add to it. Therefore inside your `foreach` when you index the `$array` by actual text key names, it fails. Those are the error messages you are seeing in reference to line 21. What it appears you *want* to do, is have all the json's combined into `$array` but without a numerical index. I may provide an answer to this. But will wait until someone comes along to provide something simpler than what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the first of the three fetched json  strings contain the desired keys/elements.

I don't see any point in fetching or processing the second two.  Even if they did contain the target keys, you should be performing early conditional returns to optimize performance.

```
public static function GetUserBrasserie($idUserBrasserie, $fk_idBrasserie, $fk_idUser) {
    $array = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://backend:5000/api/User_Brasserie/' . $idUserBrasserie), true);
    if ($array["fK_idBrasserie"] === $fK_idBrasserie && $array["fK_idUser"] === $fK_idUser) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

If you need to potentially check all three data sources AND you don't know if the target keys will exist, check them one at a time and use `isset()` to avoid notices.

```
public static function GetUserBrasserie($idUserBrasserie, $fk_idBrasserie, $fk_idUser) {
    $urls = [
        'http://backend:5000/api/User_Brasserie/' . $idUserBrasserie,
        'http://backend:5000/api/User/' . $fk_idUser,
        'http://backend:5000/api/Brasserie/' . $fk_idBrasserie,
    ];
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $array = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
        if (isset($array["fK_idBrasserie"], $array["fK_idUser"]) && $array["fK_idBrasserie"] === $fK_idBrasserie && $array["fK_idUser"] === $fK_idUser) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer i'll try that. Thank you very much

Comment: Ok i've used the second solution you've added, it's perfect